# Explicit formula for the one-dimensional distributions of a time-homogeneous Markov chain subordinated by a Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued time-homogeneous Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Poisson process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with intensity $\lambda\ge0$ and $$Y_t:=X_{N_t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

> Let $t\ge0$. Is there an explicit formula for the distribution of $Y_t$?

In particular, if $X$ is stationary, will $Y_t$ be distributed according to the law of $X_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the processes $X$ and $N$ are independent.
Then for each $A \in \mathcal{E}$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname P(Y_t \in A)
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname P(X_k \in A, N_t = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname P(X_k \in A) \operatorname P(N_t = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname P(X_k \in A) e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^k}{k!}.
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't know if this can be made more explicit in the general case, but we already see that if $X$ is stationary, then $\operatorname P(X_k \in A) = \operatorname P(X_0 \in A)$ for all $k$, so
$$
\operatorname P(Y_t \in A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname P(X_0 \in A) e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^k}{k!}
= \operatorname P(X_0 \in A),
$$
so **yes**, in this case the distribution of $Y_t$ is that of $X_0$.

Comment: I was just going to write down an answer by myself. As you say, assuming independence, we see that $Y$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process with generator $A:=\lambda(\kappa-\operatorname{id})$ and transition semigroup $(e^{tA})_{t\ge0}$.